# Проблема с преобразованием строки в массив

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой преобразования текста в массив.
Если преобразовываемый текст не содержит символов роде < или > всё нормально, массив создается, но если эти символы есть массив формируется пустым.
Пробовал преобразовывать получаемы данные с помощью `htmlspecialchars`, но в массиве создается только один элемент с нулевым индексом и всё.
В итоге имею вот такой код:

```
$gtext = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$arr = explode("/\r\n|\n|\r/", str_replace("\r", "", $gtext));
```

Вношу данные такого типа:

```
<object id="object (nt_cablebox4_01) (1)" breakable="true" interior="0" collisions="true" alpha="255" model="1628" doublesided="false" scale="1" dimension="0" posX="3173.4004" posY="-930.2998" posZ="14.3" rotX="0" rotY="0" rotZ="0"></object>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.

Comment: explode() не работает с регулярными выражениями, поэтому первым аргументом надо передавать не pcre-шаблон, а корректный символ (в вашем случае `"\r\n"`), или использовать preg_split()

Comment: попробуй так $gtext = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text'], ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: Не помогло, массив выводится в таком виде:
`Array
(
    [0] => <object id="object
<object id="object
)`

Comment: С preg_split сработало, спасибо.